# Unable to aggregate two collections using lookup in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have an orders collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "wJNEiSYwBd5ozGtLX",
    "orderId" : 52713,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-31T04:34:13.790Z"),
    "status" : "closed",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ziPzwLuZrz9MNkaRT",
            "productId" : 10290,
            "quantity" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an products collection that looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : "238cwwLkZa6gKNN86",
    "productId" : 10290,
    "title" : "Product Title",
    "price" : 9.9
}
```

I am trying to merge the price information into the orders information.

Something like:

```
{
    "_id" : "wJNEiSYwBd5ozGtLX",
    "orderId" : 52713,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-31T04:34:13.790Z"),
    "status" : "closed",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ziPzwLuZrz9MNkaRT",
            "productId" : 10290,
            "quantity" : 2,
            "price": 9.9
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try a $lookup command on MongoDB Atlas Dashboard like this:

```
{
  from: 'products',
  localField: 'orders.productId',
  foreignField: 'productId',
  as: 'priceInfo' 
}
```

The aggregated output is (not what I wanted):

```
{
    "_id" : "wJNEiSYwBd5ozGtLX",
    "orderId" : 52713,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-31T04:34:13.790Z"),
    "status" : "closed",
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ziPzwLuZrz9MNkaRT",
            "productId" : 10290,
        }
    ],
    "priceInfo": [
        {
            "_id" : "238cwwLkZa6gKNN86",
            "productId" : 10290,
            "title" : "Product Title",
            "price" : 9.9
        }
    ] 
}
```

I do not need a separate priceInfo array. It will be best if I have the product details information merged into the "orders" array. What should be the aggregation lookup syntax to achieve the desired output?

Comment: I suspect that you need to try the code, look at the results and post what the issue is. See the [$lookup syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bLqcN7tauWU

Read - [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$orders" }, // break array of orders into individual documents
  {
    $lookup: { // join
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "orders.productId",
      "foreignField": "productId",
      "as": "products"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "orders.price": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$products.price", 0 ] } // set the price
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { // group records back 
      _id: "$_id",
      createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
      status: { $first: "$status" },
      orderId: { $first: "$orderId" },
      orders: { $push: "$orders" }
    }
  }
])
```